Running Cypress in a Podman container
I'm trying to run Cypress in podman container, but I always get error of missing cypress configuration file. Here's what I have been trying:
$podman run -it  -v /srv/django/pxpro_test/CypressAutomation/:/app docker.io/bitnami/cypress run e2e/pxpro-pyapps-jstree.cy.js
It looks like this is your first time using Cypress: 13.14.1

✔  Verified Cypress! /opt/bitnami/node/cypress-cache/13.14.1/Cypress

Opening Cypress...

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:40289/devtools/browser/12b0a1d1-fa98-437c-bc31-921568db3d0c
Your configFile is invalid: /app/cypress.config.js

and without volumes:
$ podman run -it docker.io/bitnami/cypress run e2e/pxpro-pyapps--jstree.cy.js
It looks like this is your first time using Cypress: 13.14.1

✔  Verified Cypress! /opt/bitnami/node/cypress-cache/13.14.1/Cypress

Opening Cypress...

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:40909/devtools/browser/a4521dc7-e45b-41c9-8e18-55ba576889bd
Could not find a Cypress configuration file in this folder: /app

The configuration file cypress.config.js is in directory /srv/django/pxpro_test/CypressAutomation:
$ cat /srv/django/pxpro_test/CypressAutomation/cypress.config.js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
  },
});

Edit 2.9.2024:
I'm running in Linux CyppressAutomation folder:
[django@tkpyapps01p CypressAutomation]$ uname -a
Linux tkpyapps01p.ad.stat.fi 5.14.0-427.33.1.el9_4.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Aug 16 10:56:24 EDT 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[django@tkpyapps01p CypressAutomation]$ pwd
/srv/django/pxpro_test/CypressAutomation

[django@tkpyapps01p CypressAutomation]$ podman run -it  -v ./:/app bitnami/cypress run --env DEBUG="cypress:*"  --spec ./cypress/e2e/pxpro-pyapps--jstree.cy.js
It looks like this is your first time using Cypress: 13.14.1

✔  Verified Cypress! /opt/bitnami/node/cypress-cache/13.14.1/Cypress

Opening Cypress...

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:36577/devtools/browser/0594e798-8a0b-4a38-a74b-7623919a141f
Your configFile is invalid: /app/cypress.config.js

It threw an error when required, check the stack trace below:

Error: Cannot find module '/app/cypress.config.js'
Require stack:
- /opt/bitnami/node/cypress-cache/13.14.1/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/lib/plugins/child/run_require_async_child.js
- /opt/bitnami/node/cypress-cache/13.14.1/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/lib/plugins/child/require_async_child.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1140:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:177:18)
    at loadFile (/opt/bitnami/node/cypress-cache/13.14.1/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/lib/plugins/child/run_require_async_child.js:89:14)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/opt/bitnami/node/cypress-cache/13.14.1/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/lib/plugins/child/run_require_async_child.js:116:38)
    at EventEmitter.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at process.<anonymous> (/opt/bitnami/node/cypress-cache/13.14.1/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/lib/plugins/util.js:33:22)
    at process.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at emit (node:internal/child_process:944:14)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)

[django@tkpyapps01p CypressAutomation]$ cat cypress.config.js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
        on('task', {
                        log(message) {
                                console.log(message)
                                return null
        },
        table(message) {
                        console.table(message)
                        return null
        }
      })
    },

        numTestsKeptInMemory: 2,
        experimentalMemoryManagement: true,
        pageLoadTimeout: 600000,
        defaultCommandTimeout: 10000,
        redirectionLimit: 50,
  },
});

Edit2 2.9.2024, My directory structure:
[django@tkpyapps01p CypressAutomation]
$ pwd
/srv/django/pxpro_test/CypressAutomation

[django@tkpyapps01p CypressAutomation]$
ls -l

drwxr-xr-x+   5 django django    48 May 21 11:03 cypress
-rw-r--r--+   1 django django   459 Aug 26 06:21 cypress.config.js

[django@tkpyapps01p CypressAutomation]$
ls -l cypress
total 4
drwxrwxrwx+ 2 django django 4096 Sep  2 08:38 e2e
drwxr-xr-x+ 2 django django   64 May 21 11:03 fixtures
drwxr-xr-x+ 2 django django   63 Aug 23 08:23 support

[django@tkpyapps01p CypressAutomation]$
ls -l cypress/e2e
-rw-r--r--+ 1 django django 14799 Aug 28 11:42 pxpro-pyapps-editorInvalidates.cy.js
-rw-r--r--+ 1 django django  2167 Aug 26 06:21 pxpro-pyapps-editorReadsAineisto.cy.js
-rw-r--r--+ 1 django django 11908 Aug 28 11:42 pxpro-pyapps-editor-testUser.cy.js
-rw-r--r--+ 1 django django 10266 Aug 28 11:42 pxpro-pyapps-jstree.cy.js
-rw-r--r--+ 1 django django 10461 Aug 28 11:42 pxpro-pyapps-jstree-suti.cy.js
-rw-r--r--+ 1 django django 19176 Aug 23 08:23 pxpro-pyapps-publish-channels.cy.js


Maybe try  (with volumes) also adding --env DEBUG="cypress:*". This will hopefully give some more detailed output as to whats happening.

running with --env DEBUG="cypress:*"  did not help. I got just the same information as before

-v option is the correct way to map internal container path to local path, works very well for me on Linux.

I think you just need a preceding . in the volume mapping.
For example, if I navigate to the root folder of a local project I can run one of the Cypress tests with
podman run -it --name cypress -v ./:/app bitnami/cypress run --spec ./cypress/e2e/example-spec.cy.js


I'm running on Windows, so you might have to adjust things for your OS - I'm not sure what your folder structure is - but it looks like you have given an absolute path to the -v setting and it's failing silently.

I added some more information, see Edit 2.9.2024. Adding preceding . in the volume mapping did not help.

Are you navigating to the project root? (the folder containing cypress.config.js). Judging by your cat command, you are not - so as I said you will have to make adjustments. Please post the relevant folder structures.

just added Edit2 2.9.2024,that should show my directory structure on host machine
